# Make OpenCover reports available in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, code-coverage, opencover, reportgenerator

I'm trying to integrate [OpenCover](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) with [CruiseControl.NET](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/). At this point I've modified by build system so it runs my nunit tests under OpenCover. I then generate Xml and Html reports from those using [ReportGenerator](http://www.palmmedia.de/OpenSource/ReportGenerator).

Assuming it's possible to integrate the reports generated by ReportGenerator into the CruiseControl.NET webapp, how do I integrate the two?

NCover has it's own [NCoverReporting task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/NCover_Reporting_Task) that can be used, but as I'm not running NCover I can't compare its output with the XML reports generated by OpenCover.

Related thoughts / questions:

- OpenCover generates an XML file by default, but is that XML file consumable by cc.net?
- ReportGenerator also generates XML, are they intended for something like cc.net?
- cc.net has a [File-Merge](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) publisher that merges logs, but I haven't yet found any documentation indicating which file formats are useful/used by cc.net.

Comment: ReportGenerator can also produce a HTML output those files (or index.html) should be easily linkable.

Comment: See this blog post http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/9/27/cruisecontrol-net-integration-of-coverage-reports for a tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem and I solved it with these steps, take into account that I'm using msbuild, so this will only work if you're using msbuild:

1. Add a Target for Coverage
2. Add a task to your build.proj for creating the OpenCoverage output (OpenCoverReport.xml)
3. Right after after that, add a task for creating the Summary report using
   ReportGenerator (reporttypes:XML). Like so: [MSBuild Coverage Target Example](https://gist.github.com/2994278)
4. Create the XSL Transforms for creating HTML output with the Summary.xml, don't worry I wrote it already: For parsing assembly level coverage (in your build log output) use the following: [XSLT for an Assembly level coverage report](https://gist.github.com/2994289) and for parsing the Class level coverage (detailed report) use the following: [XSLT for a Class level coverage report](https://gist.github.com/2994297)
5. Add the buildReportBuildPlugin and xslReportBuildPlugin for creating both reports using the previous XSLT files in your dashboard.config file: [Add this to the configuration](https://gist.github.com/2994307)
6. Merge the coverage report summary XML file to the Build output, in your ccnet.config file: [add this to your configuration](https://gist.github.com/2994338)

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your entire configuration in the answer (would be easier to follow) - am trying to follow your steps but (1) and (2) are a little cryptic without examples...

Comment: The link in step 3 it shows the result of step 1 and 2 as well.

Comment: thank you (also realized that later). But for some reason the XSLTs that are linked here don't produce any results for me. Do they work?

Comment: @ Marcel Valdez Orozco - Can you please clarify where the file in #6 came from?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [External Links](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/ExternalLinks.html) in your ccnet.config after exposing your report via IIS

```
   <externalLinks>
     <externalLink name="Code Coverage"     url="http://cc.net/coverage" /> 
   </externalLinks>
```

Comment: seems that he can do that with the coverage reports generated by ReportGenerator then. Having never used CC I couldn't make that call thanks for the update... a +1 from me and welcome to SO :)